# Zf2 - Access layout from other module

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I have Two modules Albums And Signup. I need to set layout in Signup module.My difficulty is here , i need to set a layout.phtml for a page in  signup module , but layout.phtml is residing in Album module.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the EdpModuleLayouts https://github.com/EvanDotPro/EdpModuleLayouts

"Using EdpModuleLayouts is very, very simple. In any module config or autoloaded config file simply specify the following:"

```
array(
    'module_layouts' => array(
    'Album' => 'layout/album',
    'Signup' => 'layout/signup',
),
);
```

Comment: I got the answer , in my controller/action  used  $this->layout("anothermodule/layoutname"); And working correctly.Thankyou..